# Ester as a solvent

Tags: organic-chemistry, solvents

I am curious as to why **ester** is used often as a solvent in organic chemistry? How is it different that just using water, which is also polar? I'm sorry if this is a basic question, I'm just a student.

Answer (score 7):

- Ethyl acetate, perhaps one of the best examples that would fit in your category "often used solvents in organic chemistry" is prepared at *low cost* from ethanol and acetic acid (and these two are cheap, too).
- It may dissolve a wide range of organic material. Its low solubility in water presents as an advantage when you want to extract something.
- It has a boiling point of 77 Celsius that is elevated enough to work at moderate temperatures; yet if you want to remove it as solvent you do not spend terrible much energy to distill it off.
- Set side-by-side with other solvents, it comes with a relative *low toxicity* (at the level we know today).

Of course there is not a "one [solvent] fits for all [purposes/applications]", there are chemical conditions where other solvents are more appropriate to be deployed than esters. The presence of mineralic acids, or the of  organometallic reagents for example would call for a substitution.